# Keep ajax POST formatting / live post feed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm just working on an openvz script to run some VM's at home.
Anyway, I have been working on some js and ajax functions to send post requests, all ending up in an innerHTML section.
However, when the command is run, the result of the command is merged into a one line result, I would like to keep the original formatting because some vzctl commands produce very long outputs.
I originally had this working with PHP and a live result of the command would be outputted into the web browser.
I would like to keep the result on the same line and if possible, have it like my old setup with a sort of live console feed.
This used to work because I was just using php, but now I have AJAX on front of the php, and it removes the formatting.

```
CTID NPROC STATUS IP_ADDR HOSTNAME 101 21 running - -
```

The above is a sample output of vzlist when run with ajax, and the bottom without, how can I fix this?

```
CTID      NPROC STATUS    IP_ADDR         HOSTNAME
101         21 running   -               -
```

Also is it possible to put the ajax output into a buffer like I had with php?

```
<?php

$cmd = 'sudo '.$_POST["command"].' 2>&1';

while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen($cmd, 'r');
while (!feof($proc))
{
    echo fread($proc, 4096);
    @ flush();
}
?>
```

Current PHP file with live console.

```
function whoami () {
      $.ajax({
        url:"virt.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type
        data: "command=vzctl start 101",
        success:function(result){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =(result);
       }
     });
 }
function ls () {
      $.ajax({
        url:"virt.php", //the page containing php script
        type: "POST", //request type
        data: "command=vzlist",
        success:function(result){
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML =(result);
       }
     });
 }
```

Current html with ajax.
Sorry for the long read, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding html and filesystem line breaks when you create the data for `result`.

When generating it, I assume in php, you would place the following just after where you would like the break.

`"<br>\r\n"`

You may already be generating the newlines, if so you could wrap your output in `nl2br()`. This will create html `<br>` elements in place of newlines. See [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).